# what's the type of the Vue.Draggable "change" event?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, sortablejs, vuedraggable

I'm trying to get the type (in a typescript sense) of a `change` event from `Vue.Draggable`
https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable

but can't find its definition

the documentation shows that the event is not a browser event and has a specific payload
https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable#events

an example can be seen here :
https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/issues/338#issuecomment-361723458

I dont see it in their definition file
https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/blob/master/src/vuedraggable.d.ts

I'm far from a pro in typescript, am I missing something ?
is there another place to check ?

Comment: Most change events are just generic `Event` type.  What "change" event are you specifically talking about?  It'd be better to include some code showing where/how the event is emitted and your event handler function

Comment: thanks for the comment ! it is not a browser event, it has a specific payload rapidly  explained in the readme. I've updated my post

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your code but looking at their definition file it's likely `DragEvent` that you're after. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've submitted a feature request to get that typing added

https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/issues/1229

(they recommend to post here before submitting an issue)

Answer (score 0):

Vue.Draggable is based on Sortable.js, so you actually need types from that library. You can install `@types/sortablejs` and import type that you need.

You can check out types yourself, but as I understand you need type from `onChange` event.

[image: onChange event type]

You can import it by using:

```
import type { SortableEvent } from "sortablejs"
```

Comment: all events come from Sortable, except this specific `change` event, its not the same payload as in `SortableEvent`